# Dynamic table name based on type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three different types 1, 2, 3.

type 1 is associated with tableA
type 2 is associated with tableB
type 3 is associated with tableC

Now, I have to run the following query:

```
Alter procedure TestProc @variableType int
As
begin
   if @variableType = 'A' then 
   -- use tableA else tableB

   IF NOT EXISTS (Select field from tableA)
   print "hello"
end
```

**Edited:**
The actual query after change now looks like this:

```
if not exists(SELECT a.InstrumentId FROM tblARadiationLicenceRenewal a, tblA WHERE 
                            a.RenewalStatusID <> 790 AND a.InstrumentID = 5051747
                            AND a.LicenceExpiryDate = tblA.ExpiryDate
                            union
                            SELECT a.InstrumentID FROM tblRadiationLicenceRenewal a, tblB WHERE 
                            a.RenewalStatusID <> 790 AND a.InstrumentID = 5051747
                            AND a.LicenceExpiryDate = tblB.ExpiryDate
                            union
                            SELECT a.InstrumentID FROM tblRadiationLicenceRenewal a, tblC WHERE 
                            a.RenewalStatusID <> 790 AND a.InstrumentID = 5051747
                            AND a.LicenceExpiryDate = tblC.ExpiryDate)
                            -- PRINT 'HELLO WORLD' (THERE ARE LONG QUERIES AND STORED PROCEDURE RUNNING HERE
```

How to have table name dynamic..

Comment: Please google Dynamic SQL

Comment: is it possible without dynamic sql.. this is a fairly complicated stored proc

Comment: Nope, you need your query to be dynamic, therefore you need dynamic SQL. I guess your alternative is a `if/else if` statement to match your 3 types, with a different query in each, but you have to duplicate the entire query, not just the table name. And I'm assuming you already know how to do that.

Comment: ok thanks i try dynamic sql

Comment: You should make an effort to be **consistent** with how you write the SQL keywords - *either* write them in all UPPERCASE (SELECT, FROM), or write them in all lowercase (select, from), or in mixed case (Select, From) - but please **pick one style** and then **stick to it** - don't mix all of them together!

Comment: Is the only difference between the queries for types 1,2 and 3 the table name? Are the tables themselves different or they have the same structure?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why do you need a query / procedure that works for different tables? I see three possibilities: 1) You really want dynamic SQL, for instance for generic house keeping. 2) You are trying to provide some generic access functions, which may be a sub optimal way to deal with your database. 3) You are dealing with an inappropriate data model where you have multiple tables when it should better be only one.

Comment: ok, i have edited the question and changed the query. code is all uppercase. any suggestion other than the edited code and dynamic sql will be great

Comment: With your edit it looks like tables tblA, tblB and tblC have only one row each? Or is it many rows and you want at least one of them to match the expiry date exactly? Or are you missing some join criteria? What is the reason to have three different tables with expiry dates?

Comment: I dont know the purpose of multiple tables. I cant change the tables. Tables has many data. Join is supposed to give only one row.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace the if, you can do it without the headache of dynamic sql:

```
Alter procedure TestProc @variableType int
As
if @variableType = 'A' then 
begin
   -- use tableA

   IF NOT EXISTS (Select field from tableA)
   print "hello"
end 
else if @variableType = 'B' then 
   begin
   -- use tableB

   IF NOT EXISTS (Select field from tableB)
   print "hello"
end
```

And so on... This is the basic approach for condition in SQL stored procedure. 
You can find a lot of different approaches searching the web.

Comment: Ok, i try this one

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your procedure will be as below-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc   @variableType INT
AS
BEGIN
    IF @variableType = 1 
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Your_Field FROM   tableA)
        PRINT 'Hello from table A'
    END

    ELSE IF @variableType = 2 
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Your_Field FROM   tableB)
        PRINT 'Hello from table B'
    END

    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Your_Field FROM   tableC)
        PRINT 'Hello from table C'
    END
END
```

Comment: Ok, i try this one